# Why is my VBA script behaving so unpredictably?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am doing some IE automation in a vba script, and for some reason the

"Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")"

line of my code seems to be looping because it will sometimes launch 3-7 IE browsers instead of just one. The most aggravating part is that it works fine on my machine, but when I email it to someone else it usually doesn't run correctly. Here is my script:

```
Private Sub LauncherButton_Click()
 'Here an instance of Internet Explorer is created,
 '  and pointed at the login page
 Dim IE As InternetExplorer
 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 URL = "www.google.com"
 IE.Visible = True
 IE.Navigate URL


 'The script waits for Internet Explorer to finish loading
 Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")

 'Here the login info is taken from the user inputs and entered
 '  login page
 ID = Worksheets("home").Range("B25")
 PW = Worksheets("home").Range("B26")

 Application.SendKeys ID, True
 Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
 Application.SendKeys PW, True
 Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
 Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
 Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True

 'This command will 'click' the login button, it will remain
 '  commented until a user with access can run the script

 'Application.SendKeys "~", True

 'After the login info is entered it is removed from memory
 Worksheets("home").Range("B25").Clear
 Worksheets("home").Range("B26").Clear
 ID = ""
 PW = ""
End Sub
```

I changed the website to goggle since the actual target is only reachable on our intranet. The sendKeys portion is also irrelevant since the login page is not being loaded.

Comment: I'd recommend using Microsofts libraries, Internet Controls and HTML to use the proper objects, also, use the readystate and status rather than a 3 second loop.  Also use the object rather than send keys, so `getElementByID("UserName").value=ID`

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into it. I'll be updating this post once I make those changes

Comment: is there another way to get an element? The html code doesn't have id or tag properties.

Comment: It doesn't have a tag?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of factors all at play:

When you initiate a function the VBA code remains in the environment of that function. As I have found today, IE calls a new window once the navigate function is called. Hence your VBA will return that the connection has been lost.

Try:

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Password_AfterUpdate()
        set WebBrowser = New InternetExplorerMedium
        WebBrowser.visible = True
        WebBrowser.Navigate yourLoginPageURL

        While WebBrowser.Busy = True
            DoEvents
        Wend

        WebBrowser.Document.getElementById("UName").value = Worksheets("home").Range("B25") OR txtBoxUname.Text
        WebBrowser.Document.getElementById("UPwd").value =     Worksheets("home").Range("B26") OR txtBoxPwd.text
        Worksheets("home").Range("B25").Clear
        Worksheets("home").Range("B26").Clear
    End Sub


    Private sub cboAddress_AfterUpdate()
        if cboAddress.Text > "" then
            WebBrowser.Quit
            Set WebBrowser = Nothing
            newIE
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub newIE()
        Set WebBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        With WebBrowser
            Hwnd = .Hwnd
            .Navigate cboAddress.Text
            .Visible = True
        End With

        While WebBrowser.Busy 
            DoEvents
        Wend
    End Sub
```

You can use const = uName and Const = UPwd for your login details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm implementing this piece by piece. So far I've gone through the first sub but I'm getting a runtime error very intermittently, it says "object variable or with block variable not set". Clicking the debug button highlights the first getElement line.

Comment: Open a blank page to begin with. Navigate to the page for the first instance. Then after, close each webbrowser connection and Create new Internet explorer objects with each new navigation!

Comment: Here is a project I have just worked on. Use the IE link form in the excel file. It loads a blank Internet explorer window then you can select an address in the Web Links drop down to navigate to in the form and select Navigate to in the functions drop down of the form.

Comment: [link](http://www.ipi-international.co.uk/ipi%20web%20elements/IPI%20Web%20Elements%20x64.zip) The yourLoginPageURL needs to be blank the first time you load Internet explorer.